# Remove Duplicates in list in python

Tags: python

I have a dynamic list :

```
[{'dashboard': 'AG', 'end_date': '2021-06-17 13:13:43', 'location': 'EC & pH Reading', 'zone_name': 'Zone 1 Left'}, 

{'dashboard': 'AG', 'end_date': '2021-06-17 12:40:06', 'location': 'Harvest', 'zone_name': 'Zone 2 Left'}, 

{'dashboard': 'AG', 'end_date': '2021-06-16 15:52:52', 'location': 'Harvest', 'zone_name': 'Zone 1 Left' }, 

{'dashboard': 'AG', 'end_date': '2021-06-16 15:45:51', 'location': 'Harvest', 'zone_name': 'Zone 1 Left'}]
```

I want to remove the duplicates based on zone_name and location.
There are 3 values in zone_name. I want to remove the old one. I have sorted using the end_date. That is latest will come at top.
Now i need to remove the duplicate value based on zone_name and location.

This is what i have tried:

```
final_zone = []
res_list = []
for i in sortedArray:
     if i["location"] not in final_zone:
          sch.append(i)
          final_zone.append(i["location"])
```

What change i need to do to remove the duplicate based on zone_name and location.

That is in zone 1 left , there are 3 values, i need the latest one

Comment: Latest one. I have sorted that by end_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clean_list=[]

for elem in lst:
    # control if an element with the same zone name and location
    # is yet present in the clean list
    yet_present= len([el for el in clean_list
                if el['zone_name']==elem['zone_name']
                if el['location']==elem['location']])>0
    if not yet_present:
        clean_list.append(elem)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[{'dashboard': 'AG',
  'end_date': '2021-06-17 13:13:43',
  'location': 'EC & pH Reading',
  'zone_name': 'Zone 1 Left'},
 {'dashboard': 'AG',
  'end_date': '2021-06-17 12:40:06',
  'location': 'Harvest',
  'zone_name': 'Zone 2 Left'},
 {'dashboard': 'AG',
  'end_date': '2021-06-16 15:52:52',
  'location': 'Harvest',
  'zone_name': 'Zone 1 Left'}]
```

Comment: You have saved my day. Thanks

Comment: If my answer is useful, please upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: Need 15 reputation to upvote. i dont have that, so i cant able to do

Comment: You can accept it (instructions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/645001)

Answer (score 1):

For a general approach with an unsorted list:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

# sorting and grouping functions
f_sort = itemgetter("location", "zone_name", "end_date")  # sort by descending
f_group = itemgetter("location", "zone_name")  # group sorted by

result = [
    next(g) for _, g in  # only take latest of each group
    groupby(sorted(array, key=f_sort, reverse=True), key=f_group)
]
```

Here is some documentation on the used utils (all of which are really handy in a lot of use cases):

- [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
- [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)
- [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)
- [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable `result`, and for each dictionary item in the `data` list, check if its already there in the result, if yes don't append, else `append` it to the result list.

```py
result = []
for item in data:
    if item['zone_name'] in (x['zone_name'] for x in result):
        continue
    result.append(item)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
[{'dashboard': 'AG',
  'end_date': '2021-06-17 13:13:43',
  'location': 'EC & pH Reading',
  'zone_name': 'Zone 1 Left'},
 {'dashboard': 'AG',
  'end_date': '2021-06-17 12:40:06',
  'location': 'Harvest',
  'zone_name': 'Zone 2 Left'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through the list and memorize the indices you want to keep.

```
keepers = {}
for i in range(len(sorted_array)):
    keepers(sorted_array[i]['location'])=i ## Will be overwritten if the zone_name repeats

final_array = []
for i in keepers.values():
    final_array.append(sorted_array[i])
```

As a bonus, you get a list of all zones in `keepers.keys()`.

But your approach might actually also work. Just change `sch.append(i)` to `res_list.append(i)` and change the order of the iterable (`for i in sorted_array[::-1]`), so the last and not the first one gets kept.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers work but I want to add a solution using [`Pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

you can create a dataframe from your list of dictionaries:

```
import pandas as pd
d = [{'dashboard': 'AG', 'end_date': '2021-06-17 13:13:43', 'location': 'EC & pH Reading', 'zone_name': 'Zone 1 Left'}, {'dashboard': 'AG', 'end_date': '2021-06-17 12:40:06', 'location': 'Harvest', 'zone_name': 'Zone 2 Left'}, 

{'dashboard': 'AG', 'end_date': '2021-06-16 15:52:52', 'location': 'Harvest', 'zone_name': 'Zone 1 Left' }, 

{'dashboard': 'AG', 'end_date': '2021-06-16 15:45:51', 'location': 'Harvest', 'zone_name': 'Zone 1 Left'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

This is what df looks like:

```
dashboard             end_date         location    zone_name
0        AG  2021-06-17 13:13:43  EC & pH Reading  Zone 1 Left
1        AG  2021-06-17 12:40:06          Harvest  Zone 2 Left
2        AG  2021-06-16 15:52:52          Harvest  Zone 1 Left
3        AG  2021-06-16 15:45:51          Harvest  Zone 1 Left
```

Sort of like a table in excel.

Now with one line, you can do exactly what you want:

```
df.sort_by("end_date").drop_duplicates(["location", "zone_name"], keep="last")
```

output:

```
  dashboard             end_date         location    zone_name
2        AG  2021-06-16 15:52:52          Harvest  Zone 1 Left
1        AG  2021-06-17 12:40:06          Harvest  Zone 2 Left
0        AG  2021-06-17 13:13:43  EC & pH Reading  Zone 1 Left
```